# how to build validation error code for i18n

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, internationalization, bean-validation

I'm writing REST-API using Spring MVC framework.
I'm using bean-validation like:

```
class Person {
    @NotNull
    String name;
    @NotNull
    String email;
    @Min(0)
    Integer age;
}
```

I'm validating `Person` using `@Valid` annotation into controllers:

```
@PostMapping
public Person create(@Valid @RequestBody Person person) {return ...;}
```

To make errors human-readable I use spring's top level error handler:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    @ResponseBody String handle(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
        List<String> errors = ex.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors().stream()
                .map(this::buildMessage)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return errors.toString();
    }

    private String buildMessage(FieldError fe) {
        return fe.getField() + " " + fe.getDefaultMessage();
    }
}
```

So my errors looks like: `[name may not be null, email may not be null]`

Now I need to use language independent `error code` that will be parsed by different UIs to implement i18n.
**Is there any way to build full error code?** (that contains field name)

I see the following solutions:

1. Use custom message every time I used annotation (ugly):

   ```
   class Person {
       @NotNull(message="app.error.person.name.not.null")
       String name;
       @NotNull(message="app.error.person.email.not.null")
       String email;
       @Min(0)(message="app.error.person.age.below.zero")
       Integer age;
   }
   ```
2. Build correct code into my exception handler(don't know how):

   ```
   private String buildMessage(FieldError fe) {
       return "app.error." +
               fe.getObjectName() + "." +
               fe.getField() + "." +
               fe.getDefaultMessage().replaceAll("\\s", "");//don't know how to connect to concrete annotation
   }
   ```

   so message will be like `app.error.person.name.maynotbenull`
3. Re-write all annotations and validators for them to build correct message by removing default ConstraintViolation and adding custom (overhead)

Answer (score 2):

No need to specify message inside annotation . It will be an overhead

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomExceptionHandler {

  @Autowired
  MessageSource messageSource;

  @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
  @ResponseBody String handle(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
    List<String> errors = ex.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors().stream()
            .map(this::buildMessage)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return errors.toString();
  }

  private String buildMessage(FieldError fe) {
    StringBuilder errorCode = new StringBuilder("");
    String localizedErrorMsg = "";
    errorCode.append("error").append(".");
    errorCode.append(fe.getObjectName()).append(".");
    errorCode.append(fe.getField()).append(".");
    errorCode.append(fe.getCode().toLowerCase());

        try {
            localizedErrorMsg = this.messageSource.getMessage(errorCode,(Object[]) null, LocaleContextHolder.getLocale());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            localizedErrorMsg = fe.getDefaultMessage();
        }
    return localizedErrorMsg;
  }
}
```

And in the message file(i18n) use the following format

```
error.person.name.notnull = Name must not be null
error.person.email.notnull = Email must not be null
error.person.age.min= Minimum age should greater than 0.
```

Using this you don't have to write any message code in the annotation.
Hopefully this will help.

Comment: I don't need to localize my message, but ok, I can just throw away try block.

Comment: I want to ask in which case `fe.getCode()` will return `null`?

Comment: fe.getCode() will never return null. MethodArgumentNotValidException will be thrown because of that code only

Comment: but we have constructor for `FieldError` that set `codes` to `null`

Comment: In FiledError 2 constructor are available. If annotation is present it will call the second one which will set the value of code